# How to reduce this object with children?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following object:

```
{
  "name": "A",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B",
      "open": false,
      "registry": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "C",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "D",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "E",
          "registry": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to reduce this tree and get only nodes where `registry` is true.

First I tried to find all nodes:

```
public nodesRegistry = new Map();

findRegistryNodes(node: TreeNode) {
  if (!node) return;

  if (node?.registry) {
    this.nodesRegistry.set(node, node);
  }

  if (node.children)
    node.children.forEach((node: TreeNode) => {
      this.findRegistryNodes(node);
    });
}
```

The to rebuild tree again:

```
const parents = this.getParentNodeRegistry();
const children = this.getChildrenNodeRegistry(parents);
```

This method  collects all parent nodes for found children:

```
getParentNodeRegistry() {
  const nodesWithRegistry = new Map<string, TreeNode>();

  for (const node of this.nodesRegistry.keys()) {
    let parent = node.parent;

    do {
      if (parent.parent && !parent.parent.parent) {
          nodesWithRegistry.set(parent.name, parent);
          break;
      }

      parent = parent.parent;
    } while (parent);
  }

  return nodesWithRegistry;
}
```

Then collect all children:

```
getChildrenNodeRegistry(nodes: Map<string, TreeNode>) {
    return Array.from(nodes.values()).reduce((children, node) => {
        this.reduceNodesWithRegistrer(node);
        return (children = children.concat(node));
    }, []);
}
```

As result I get nodes with not property `registry: true`.

How to fix it?

Comment: That's not a "tree", that's an object

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research, search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+object+recursively+get+node+with+value+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Liam an object that represents a tree.

Comment: What should happen if the node `registry != true`? Should he and his descendants be removed? In this case, in your example, the tree will be empty.

Comment: I just remove this nodes from tree and dont show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what do you need:

```js
const value = {
  name: "A",
  children: [
    {
      name: "B",
      open: false,
      registry: true,
      children: [
        {
          name: "C",
          children: [
            {
              name: "D",
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "E",
          registry: true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function getRegistryTrue(value) {
  let { children, ...rest } = value;
  const newValue = { ...rest };

  if (children) {
    children = children.filter(({ registry }) => !!registry);
    newValue['children'] = children.map((c) => getRegistryTrue(c));
  }

  return newValue;
}

console.log(getRegistryTrue(value));
```

Comment: This is does not work when parent has not registry true, but some of children have

Comment: Try to run this script for this tree: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.61656df45fd24857815c04e58bbda28d&right=local.qoluni

Comment: just add   `if (!value.registry) return {};` at the first line in the `getRegistryTrue` function. Also the  json data in the URL is different than in stackoverflow.

Comment: It returns me empty result as `{}`

Comment: Could you find your answer I will accept if it works

Comment: Because your parent is as Object. eventually, you can replace `{}` with `undefined`. I don't know exactly what result you expect in this case.

Comment: Check out my JSON in jsononline, it has full JSON object. I need to  get tree where registry: true only these nodes with parents

Comment: so provide me with an example of this tree where `registry: true`

Comment: I have tried this: `function getRegistryTrue(value:any) {
  let { children, id, ...rest } = value;
  const newValue = { ...rest };

  if (children) {
    children = children.filter((data: any) => !!data?.registry || !data?.id);
    newValue['children'] = children.map((c: any) => getRegistryTrue(c));
    if(newValue?.children.length ==0 ) return {};
  }

  return newValue;
}`

Comment: Here tree with registry: true:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.61656df45fd24857815c04e58bbda28d&right=local.qoluni

Comment: You provided me with my function in TS. I don't understand what are you expecting with objects from this URL.

Comment: Check out my fix here: https://jsfiddle.net/rypzxv71/